# How to create mixin to use @property in classes

Tags: python, django

I've got the following class

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in UserProfile._meta.fields]
```

I want to use that property on all my classes. So I want to make a mixin.

```
class HelperMixin(object):
    @property
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in UserProfile._meta.fields]
```

Trouble is, the property has class specific code in it. How do I generalize the code to work in other classes?

And what is the difference when I use it like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model, HelperMixin)
```

vs. like this

```
class UserProfile(HelperMixin, models.Model)
```

Comment: That's kind of hard to answer in the abstract.  What is the nature of the dependency?  You could possibly use `for field in self.__class__._meta.fields` or even `self._meta.fields`.

Comment: side note: good style is to not use 'get_' prefix on properties. Just use `fields` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self._meta.fields`, class members are available on instances as well:

```
class HelperMixin(object):
    @property
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in self._meta.fields]
```

The differense between `class UserProfile(models.Model, HelperMixin)` and `class UserProfile(HelperMixin, models.Model)` lies in the MRO (method resolution order).  It would seem natural to have the mixin before the base class, but as long as the base and the mixin does not have members with the same name it makes no difference.

Comment: I use this on the front end with this script: https://gist.github.com/broinjc/83ae49b9e198a2776929